# Updating environment global variable in Jenkins pipeline from the stage level - is it possible?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `Jenkinsfile` with some global variables and some stages.
can I update the global variable out from a stage?

An example:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {                 
    PASSWD = "${sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'python -u do_some_something.py')}"
    ACC = "HI"
  }

  stage('stage1') {
      when { expression { params.UPDATE_JOB == false } }

      steps{
        script {
          def foo= sh(  returnStdout: true, script: 'python -u do_something.py ')
          env.ACC =  foo
          println foo
          print("pw")
          println env.PASSWD
       }
     }  
   }
}
```

Is it possible to update the `ACC` variable with the value from foo, so that I can use the `ACC` Variable in the next stage?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can't override the environment variable defined in the `environment {}` block. However, there is one trick you might want to use. You can refer to `ACC` environment variable in two ways:

- explicitly by `env.ACC`
- implicitly by `ACC`

The value of `env.ACC` cannot be changed once set inside `environment {}` block, but `ACC` behaves in the following way: when the variable `ACC` is not set then the value of `env.ACC` gets accessed (if exists of course). But when `ACC` variable gets initialized in any stage, `ACC` refers to this newly set value in any stage. Consider the following example:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        FOO = "initial FOO env value"
    }

    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "FOO is '${FOO}'" // prints: FOO is 'initial FOO env value'

                    env.BAR = "bar"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Stage 2") {
            steps {
                echo "env.BAR is '${BAR}'" // prints: env.BAR is 'bar'
                echo "FOO is '${FOO}'" // prints: FOO is 'initial FOO env value'
                echo "env.FOO is '${env.FOO}'" // prints: env.FOO is 'initial FOO env value'
                script {
                    FOO = "test2"
                    env.BAR = "bar2"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Stage 3") {
            steps {
                echo "FOO is '${FOO}'" // prints: FOO is 'test2'
                echo "env.FOO is '${env.FOO}'" // prints: env.FOO is 'initial FOO env value'
                echo "env.BAR is '${BAR}'" // prints: env.BAR is 'bar2'

                script {
                    FOO = "test3"
                }

                echo "FOO is '${FOO}'" // prints: FOO is 'test3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And as you can see in the above example, the only exception to the rule is if the environment variable gets initialized outside the `environment {}` block. For instance, `env.BAR` in this example was initialized in `Stage 1`, but the value of `env.BAR` could be changed in `Stage 2` and `Stage 3` sees changed value.

### UPDATE 2019-12-18

There is one way to override the environment variable defined in the `environment {}` block - you can use `withEnv()` block that will allow you to override the existing env variable. It won't change the value of the environment defined, but it will override it inside the `withEnv()` block. Take a look at the following example:

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any 

  stages {
    stage("Test") {
      environment {
        FOO = "bar"
      }

      steps {
        script {
          withEnv(["FOO=newbar"]) {
            echo "FOO = ${env.FOO}" // prints: FOO = newbar
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> I also encourage you to check my ["Jenkins Pipeline Environment Variables explained
>   "](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwQDxwZRZiE) video.

Comment: Nice answer. I have been stuffing about with this for half a day, and this answer is exactly what i needed!!

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation with a working piece of code. I've been googling around in search of this for HOURS now.

Comment: Thank you, Tommi! You can find even more examples in the blog post I wrote some time ago about this specific problem - https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: Updating environment variables looks easy now. Thanks

Comment: Wow, I never saw "cannot be changed once set inside environment {} block" anywhere in the Jenkins docs... I've been trying to figure out why setting `env.FOO` was not working at all in my script for about 6 hours now... :facepalm: Jenkins is such a nightmare.

Comment: thanks for the tips,  now i just do env.myvariable="sometihng" in the steps and i can use them. and overidem along any of the steps,  i was putting them in the environmentStep =(...  now is easy stuff, thanks again.

Comment: thanks, now i just create variables  in the steps   as env.Myvar  so i can use them and overide them in other steps, =)

Comment: Could someone help point me to the Jenkins source code that implements this rule? i.e.,  "cannot be changed once set inside environment {} block"

Comment: it seems the global Variables in jenkins file was different with the configuration UI. I was using the pipeline configuration UI, i change the global variable value in somewhere (eg powershell) and it was changed accordingly with echo, but in the mail notification the value still was the initial one.  that was confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Each stage can read, write, or append to a script that helps pass the environment variables from stage to stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Set A and B') {
            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe
                echo "" > jobinfo.sh
                A=3
                echo "A=${A}" >> jobinfo.sh
                B=4
                echo "B=${B}" >> jobinfo.sh
                '''
            }
        }
        
        stage('Set C') {
            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe
                . jobinfo.sh
                ((C=A+B))
                echo "C=${C}" >> jobinfo.sh
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('Result') {
            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash -xe
                . jobinfo.sh
                echo "Result is ${C}" # 7
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
loggedInUser = ""
node ("cm-windows") {
withEnv(["UserLoggedIn='Vrishali'"]) {
  echo env.UserLoggedIn       
   stage('Setup'){
    def buildCause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0]
    def buildPrincipal = [type:"unknown", name:""]
    def buildUserCause = 
    currentBuild.getRawBuild().getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause)
    buildPrincipal = [type:"user", name:buildCause.userId]
    print "Prining.."
    print buildCause.userId
    print "Checking the env var"
    print env.UserLoggedIn
    echo "[*] Starting build (id: ${env.UserLoggedIn}) on ${env.UserLoggedIn}"  
    loggedInUser = buildCause.userId
    echo "Loggedin user"
    print loggedInUser
    echo loggedInUser
   } 
}
stage ('override env'){         
   withEnv(["UserLoggedIn=${loggedInUser}"]) {
       echo "inside 2 stgae"
        echo loggedInUser
        print loggedInUser 
        echo "env"
        echo env.UserLoggedIn
   }
}
```

}