# To set the value of an env variable base of the build cause in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Here is a pseudo-code :
wherein "env1" and "env2" are two env variables which I want to use in some definition in the later stage

```
pipeline {
        agent {
    .
    .
    .
  environment {
        BUILD_CAUSE = getCause(currentBuild)
        env1 = (to be set to true when BUILD_CAUSE is Gerritcause and should be set to false when build cause is Timetriggercause)
        env2 = "true"
  }

 stage('use the env'){
       steps{
          node('master') {
           build.useenv("$env1","$env2")
          }
       }
     }
   .
   .
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541813/10721630. It describes how env variables function and how to set/overwrite them.

Comment: script {
            if ( '${env.BUILD_CAUSE}' == 'GerritCause' ){
                env.env2 = "false"
            } else if ( '${env.BUILD_CAUSE}' == 'TimerTriggerCause' ) {
                env.env2 = "true"
            }
          }
          sh 'echo '${env1}''  -> is not printing anything, I have not declared any env in the environment section.

Comment: `env1` wasn't set anywhere.

Comment: Ohh it's sh echo env2 only. Typed wrong by mistake.

Comment: What if `env.BUILD_CAUSE` is neither `GerritCause` nor `TimerTriggerCause`? Then `env1` is not set and `sh "echo ${env1}"` will not print anything.

Comment: It is GerritCaue, I am printing that on the top.