# Jenkins variable defined inside global variable(env variable)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have defined an environment(global) variable in jenkins via configuration as

```
REPORT = "Test, ${CycleNumber},${JOB_NAME}"
```

I have 1 parameter defined in my pipeline called Cycle which has values new & update. Based on this cycle value CycleNumber should be updated and I tried it via groovy using script block in my pipeline as below

```
if(Cycle == "New")
    {
        CycleNumber = "12345"
    }
else if (Cycle == "Update")
    {
       CycleNumber = "7890"
    }
```

after this update if I do echo "${env.REPORT}" I get the value as "Test,,TestJob" where in the CycleNumber variable is not updated. Could you please let me know if there is a way to update this CycleNumber field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on Groovy's String interpolation to replace the `CycleNumber`. You can have your own placeholder(e.g: `_CYCLE_NUMBER_`) in the environment variable which you can replace later in your flow. Take a look at the following example.

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  stages {
    stage("Test") {
      environment {
        REPORT = "Test, _CYCLE_NUMBER_,${JOB_NAME}"
      }

      steps {
        script {
            def Cycle = 'New'
            def CycleNumber = 'none'
            if(Cycle == "New"){
                    CycleNumber = "12345"
            } else if (Cycle == "Update") {
                   CycleNumber = "7890"
            }

            def newReport = "$REPORT".replace('_CYCLE_NUMBER_', CycleNumber)
            echo "$newReport" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also once you set the newReport variable, make sure you use the same variable. if you do `"${env.REPORT}"` you will always get the original value assigned the tne environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. implemented the solution. works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with a workaround here: [Updating environment global variable in Jenkins pipeline from the stage level - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541489/updating-environment-global-variable-in-jenkins-pipeline-from-the-stage-level)

TLDR:
You can't override a global environment variable that has been declared in environment(global), however you can use the withEnv() function to wrap your script block in your pipeline to reference the updated value, eg:

```
withEnv(['REPORT=...']) {
  // do something with updated env.REPORT
}
```