# Jenkins - Pass a variable from a stage to a function inside another stage

Tags: variables, jenkins

in Jenkins, I want to pass value of a variable from a stage to a function (defined in library) in another stage. I tested with env variables, but the function will take the initial value of the variable. my jenkinsfile code is:

```
@Library('shared-library')_

pipeline {
  agent any
environment {
    TF_WORK_DIR = '.'
}

stages {
    stage('Set-Environment') {
        steps {
            script {
                println("----------------------------Init Script-----------------------------")
                TF_WORK_DIR = "file"
            }}
    }

    stage('Init') {
        steps {
            script{
                    println("TF_WORK_DIR in init is ${TF_WORK_DIR}")
                    if (TF_WORK_DIR != ".") {   
                            println("TF_WORK_DIR in if condition init is ${TF_WORK_DIR}")
                            function()
                    }
                    else {
            println("TF_WORK_DIR in else condition init is ${TF_WORK_DIR}")
                        function()
                    }      
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

My function is

```
def call(timeoutMinutes = 10) {

try {
    echo "TF_WORK_DIR inside function ${TF_WORK_DIR}"
} catch (Exception e) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    echo "An error occurred: ${e.getMessage()}\n"
}}
```

Current output is

```
----------------------------Init Script-----------------------------
TF_WORK_DIR in TF init is file
TF_WORK_DIR in if condition TF init is file
TF_WORK_DIR inside function .
```

expected output

```
    ----------------------------Init Script-----------------------------
    TF_WORK_DIR in init is file
    TF_WORK_DIR in if condition init is file
    TF_WORK_DIR inside function file
```

I also tried to define the variable outside of pipeline instead of inside environment bloc, but it didn't work
am I missing something? how to make the function to take the updated value of TF_WORK_DIR ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use environment variables to pass a value to a function, use a function parameter or if need be a global function. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541813/3623345) for limitations to changing env variables defined in the `environment` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended by changing my function code to accept a parameter and passed that variable as parameter. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define variable outside declarative pipeline :

```
#library function
def myFunc(
      Map source_config = [:], 
      Map updates = [:]){
  updates.each{ k,v -> 
    source_config[k] = v
  }
  return source_config
}
def Map myMap = [:]

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages{
    stage('a'){
      steps{
        script{
          myMap.paramA = 'test'
          myMap.paramB = 'test'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('B'){
      steps{
        script{
          myMap = myFunc( myMap, [ paramA :134])
          print(myMap.paramA)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that didn't worked for me. same behavior.

Comment: @user3146966 you need to return something from function to update your variables. See updated answer