# How to pass sensitive dynamic values as an argument in jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is the Jenkinsfile. The execution fails because the subnet id does not get its value in the second bat command to add subnet to storage account firewall. The complete scenario is that I am deploying infrastrucutre(one vm inside a vnet) to Azure using terraform via jenkins pipeline, once this is deployed, in the next stages the workflow is to whitelist the same subnet to the storage account firewall.

```java
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        AZURE_RG = 'myrg'
        VNET_NAME = 'myvnet'
        STORAGE_ACCOUNT_RG = 'str_rg'
        STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'str_name'
        SUBNET_ID = ''  // Initialize SUBNET_ID variable
    }

    stages {
        stage('Get Subnet ID') {
            steps {
                script {
                // Construct Azure CLI command dynamically with Groovy string interpolation
                    def azCliCommand = "az network vnet subnet show -g ${AZURE_RG} -n default --vnet-name ${VNET_NAME} --query id --output tsv"
                    // Get subnet ID
                    SUBNET_ID = bat(script: azCliCommand, returnStdout: true).trim()

                    // Add subnet to storage account network rules
                    bat "az storage account network-rule add -g ${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_RG} --account-name ${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME} --subnet ${SUBNET_ID} --bypass AzureServices"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The execution fails because the subnet id does not get its value in the second bat command to add subnet to storage account firewall. The complete scenario is that I am deploying infrastrucutre (one vm inside a vnet) to Azure using terraform via jenkins pipeline, once this is deployed, in the next stages the workflow is to whitelist the same subnet to the storage account firewall.

Expected Results: the value of subnetid must be passed as an argument in the second bat command and the subnet must get whitelisted to the storage account.

Comment: I'm not sure that the title "How to pass sensitive dynamic values as an argument in jenkins pipeline" relates to the actual question. I just realized that currently it looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541489/updating-environment-global-variable-in-jenkins-pipeline-from-the-stage-level

Answer (score 0):

This is because:

- your empty `SUBNET_ID` is defined in the `environment` block - once it's defined there, it [cannot be updated within the stage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541813/16417367);
- `SUBNET_ID` defined in the `script` block is a different variable. If you want to use the environment variable in Groovy, you need to refer it as `env.SUBNET_ID`.

If you only need the `SUBNET_ID` variable value within the `bat` script, try to delete the environment variable definition.

If you need the same variable to be shared between the stages, define it before the `pipeline` block.

Comment: I removed the variable definition from the environment block however, the issue remains the same that the variable subnetid in the second command takes the entire script(z network vnet subnet show -g ${AZURE_RG} -n default --vnet-name ${VNET_NAME} --query id --output tsv) as the value from the previous command instead of substituting the subnetid as  a string. The error output is like this:

Comment: Warning: A secret was passed to "bat" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
   Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [AZURE_CREDS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID]
   See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\storagefw>az storage account network-rule add -g str_rg  --account-name str_name --subnet C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\storagefw network vnet subnet show -g devtest -n default --vnet-name myvnet --query id --output tsv  1>az 
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: network vnet subnet show

Comment: Note that the subnetid contains the subscription id too, which is a sensitive string, in that case how do I pass value to the variable subnet while whitelisting it to the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

you can define it as a global environment variable outside of any stage block

try this

```
    environment {
        AZURE_RG = 'myrg'
        VNET_NAME = 'myvnet'
        STORAGE_ACCOUNT_RG = 'str_rg'
        STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'str_name'
        SUBNET_ID = ''  // Initialize SUBNET_ID variable
    }

    stages {
        stage('Get Subnet ID') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Construct Azure CLI command dynamically with Groovy string interpolation
                    def azCliCommand = "az network vnet subnet show -g ${AZURE_RG} -n default --vnet-name ${VNET_NAME} --query id --output tsv"
                    // Get subnet ID
                    SUBNET_ID = bat(script: azCliCommand, returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Whitelist Subnet') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Add subnet to storage account network rules
                    bat "az storage account network-rule add -g ${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_RG} --account-name ${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME} --subnet ${SUBNET_ID} --bypass AzureServices"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Variables defined in `environment` block cannot be overridden. You can check out the link in my answer for more details.